# how to add datepicker( dates start and end date) in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I need to add a date picker that contains start and end dates. When a date is selected that should pass to API to display chart. I have currently displaying Apexchart but I need date picker for my code.

Below is my chart displaying currently now I am passing selected key and I am not getting how to pass selected date to chart.

```
Here I need to add date picker        

<template>
     <div >
      <select  v-model="PoleSelected" @change="getPoleDetail()"  >
       <option :value='0'>Select Pole</option>
      <option v-for='data in PoleList' :value='data.poleid'>{{ data.poleid}} 
      </option> 
       </select>

//above dorpdown is used to select the pole 

     <va-card >
         <h3>Temperture</h3>
       <AreachartTemp :_key="PoleSelected" />  //this is my 
   //AreachartTemp.vue anther pageand i am passing selected key to this page
      </va-card>
     </div> 

     <div >
     <va-card>
        <h3>Humidity</h3>
       <AreachartHumd  :_key="PoleSelected"/>  //this is also sepearte 
       // page and i am passing selected key 
   </va-card>
     </div>
  </template>
 <script>
  export default{
   data:function() {
      return {
       PoleSelected:'',
              }                
         },
  components: {
      AreachartTemp,
     AreachartHumd,
   },
    }
  </script>



//below is my AreachartTemp.vue page

      <template>
            <div   id="wrapper">
          <div id="chart-bar" >
            <apexchart type=area height=200 :options="chartOptionsArea0" 
         :series="series0"/>
          </div>
          <div id="chart-bar">
            <apexchart type=area height=100 :options="chartOptionsBrush0" 
         :series="series0" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </template>
      <script>
       import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
      Vue.use(VueApexCharts)
      Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts)
      import axios from 'axios'
       import Vue from 'vue';
      export default {

        props: {
          _key: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
        },
            data() {
              return {

       series0: [{
                  data: this.generateDayWiseTimeSeries0(  185, {
                    min: 30,
                    max: 90
                  })
                }],
                chartOptionsArea0: {
                  chart: {
                    id: 'chartArea0',
                    foreColor: "#ccc",
                    toolbar: {
                      autoSelected: 'pan',
                      show: false
                    }
                  },                                                                                              
               stroke: {
                    width: 3
                  },
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                  fill: {
                    opacity: 1,
                  },
                    markers: {
                      size: 2,
                      colors: ["#000524"],
                      strokeColor: "#00BAEC",
                      strokeWidth: 3
                    },

                  xaxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                  }
                },
                chartOptionsBrush0: {
                  chart: {
                    id: 'chartBrush',
                    brush: {
                      target: 'chartArea0',
                      enabled: true
                    },
                    selection: {
                      enabled: true,
                      xaxis: {

                      }
                    },
                  },
                  colors: ['#546E7A'],
                  fill: {
                    type: 'gradient',
                    gradient: {
                     opacityFrom: 0.55,
                      opacityTo: 0
                    }
                  },
                  xaxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tooltip: {
                      enabled: false
                    }
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    tickAmount: 2
                  }
                }
               };
            },
            watch: {
              _key() {

                this.generateDayWiseTimeSeries0();
              }
            },
            mounted() {

              //this.updateChart();
            },
                  methods: {
               generateDayWiseTimeSeries0: function () {
                      var me = this;
            axios.get("http://34.67.88.0:3000/api/eco/temp/"+this._key)
                          .then(function (res) {

                              me.series0[0].data=res.data
                               /*me.$children[0].updateSeries([{
                                 data: res.data
                               }]);
                               me.$children[1].updateSeries([{
                                 data: res.data
                               }]);*/
                          })

                      return []

              }
                  }
      };
      </script>
```

Comment: Which UI framework do you use? Is there a datepicker component? Where `PoleSelected` value come from? There isn't `data` or `props` in your component. It's not clear. Can you improve your example?

Comment: i have updated code, please check it ,    UI framework   : vuejs (vue atlas)  ,   it don't have date picker component (need to be added )